# Evitar registro duplicado de datos en php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, php7

Tengo un formulario, el cual mediante ajax envío información a php para que la procese y registre en una base de datos.

El problema es que en ocasiones duplica información y por consiguiente la registra varias veces en la bd.
He estado buscando soluciones y la verdad es que solo he encontrado respuestas pero solo para cuando ya registre información una vez y nuevamente trato de registrar esa misma información.

Como por ejemplo usar un `SELECT`

Validar que antes de hacer el registro no exista en la base de datos:

```
$nuevo_usuario=mysql_query("select nombre from $tabla where nombre='$nombre'");

if(mysql_num_rows($nuevo_usuario)>0)
 // mensaje de error
else
 //hacemos la inserción
```

En mi caso es otra cosa porque como lo mencione arriba mando información a php mediante ajax y en ese mismo envío es donde se duplica la información, no se si es problema de ajax o de php.

Mi código ajax:

```
function insert()
{
    var formulario = $("#form-registro");
    
    var folio = $("#folioVal").val();
    var fecha = $("#fechaVal").val();
    var id_cliente = $("#id_clienteVal").val();
    var id_ubicacion = $("#id_ubicacionVal").val();
    var pago = $("#pagoVal").val();
    var distribuidor = $("#distribuidorVal").val();
    var status = 0;
    
    if(pago == 2)
    {
        status = $('input[name=rfactura]:checked').val();
        
        status = status != 1 && status != 2 ? 0 : status; 
        
        if(status == 0)
        {
            Swal.fire('Por favor selecciona si el pago a crédito será con o sin factura.', '', 'warning');
            return false;
        }           
    }
    
    var articulos = [];
    
    $(".articuloVal").each(function(){
        var id_articulo = $(this).val();
        var cantidad = $(this).parent(0).siblings("div").children(".cantidadVal").val();
        var monto = $(this).parent(0).parent(0).children(".importeVal").val();
        
        var articulo = {"id_articulo" : id_articulo, "cantidad" : cantidad, "monto" : monto}
        articulos.push(articulo);
    });
    
    if(formulario.valid())
    {
     $.ajax({
        url: "../includes/acciones/control_nota/insert.php",
        data: "folio=" + folio + "&fecha=" + fecha + "&id_cliente=" + id_cliente 
            + "&id_ubicacion=" + id_ubicacion + "&articulos=" + JSON.stringify(articulos)
            + "&pago=" + pago + "&distribuidor=" + distribuidor + "&status=" + status,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data == 1)
            {
                Swal.fire('Registro realizado exitosamente.', '', 'success').then((result) => {
                  if(result.value) {
                    window.location.href = "registro_nota.php";
                  }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                Swal.fire('Hubo un problema al realizar el registro.', '', 'error');
            }
        }
     });
    }
}
```

Este es mi código php:

```
<?php
include_once("../../clases/class.Nota.php");

extract($_POST);
# folio
# fecha
# id_cliente
# id_ubicacion
# articulos
# pago
# distribuidor
# status

$articulos = json_decode(stripslashes($articulos));

$fecha = explode("/", $fecha, 3);
$fecha = $fecha[2]."-".$fecha[1]."-".$fecha[0];

$id_nota = Nota::insert($folio, $fecha, $id_cliente, $id_ubicacion, $pago, trim(strtoupper($distribuidor)), $status);

if($id_nota > 0)
{
    $nota = new Nota($id_nota);
    
    foreach($articulos as $articulo)
    {
       $nota->setDetalleNota($articulo->id_articulo, $articulo->cantidad, $articulo->monto);
    }

    echo 1;
}
else
  echo 0;
?>
```

Como podría solucionar esto??

Comment: Hola Jorge, cómo estás agregando el evento al formulario?.  En ocaciones, cuando se hace el envío de datos mediante un formulario el servidor demora en responder esto puede generar que el usuario pulse nuevamente el botón de enviar, provocando que se realicen registros duplicados. Por lo que podrías controlar que suceda esto deshabilitando el botón o realizando una comprobación previa al envió.

Comment: ¿Cuál campo (o conjunto de campos) debe ser único?

Comment: @aberon10 no estoy agregando ningún evento al formulario si no al botón: <burton type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="insert();">Guardar</button>

Comment: @Triby el campo que no se debe repetir es el de folio

Comment: ¿Cómo buscas una nota por folio?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes verificar si ya se realizo una petición para que no volver a efectuarla. Para esto puedes definir una variable que controle el estado en el cual se encuentra esta:

```
let dataSent = false;

function insert() {
  let formulario = $("#form-registro");

  let folio = $("#folioVal").val();
  let fecha = $("#fechaVal").val();
  let id_cliente = $("#id_clienteVal").val();
  let id_ubicacion = $("#id_ubicacionVal").val();
  let pago = $("#pagoVal").val();
  let distribuidor = $("#distribuidorVal").val();
  let status = 0;

  if (pago == 2) {
    status = $("input[name=rfactura]:checked").val();

    status = status != 1 && status != 2 ? 0 : status;

    if (status == 0) {
      Swal.fire(
        "Por favor selecciona si el pago a crédito será con o sin factura.",
        "",
        "warning"
      );
      return false;
    }
  }

  let articulos = [];

  $(".articuloVal").each(function () {
    let id_articulo = $(this).val();
    let cantidad = $(this)
      .parent(0)
      .siblings("div")
      .children(".cantidadVal")
      .val();
    let monto = $(this).parent(0).parent(0).children(".importeVal").val();

    let articulo = {
      id_articulo: id_articulo,
      cantidad: cantidad,
      monto: monto,
    };
    articulos.push(articulo);
  });

  if (formulario.valid() && !dataSent) {
    dataSent = true;
    $.ajax({
      url: "../includes/acciones/control_nota/insert.php",
      data:
        "folio=" +
        folio +
        "&fecha=" +
        fecha +
        "&id_cliente=" +
        id_cliente +
        "&id_ubicacion=" +
        id_ubicacion +
        "&articulos=" +
        JSON.stringify(articulos) +
        "&pago=" +
        pago +
        "&distribuidor=" +
        distribuidor +
        "&status=" +
        status,
      type: "POST",
      success: function (data) {
        if (data == 1) {
          Swal.fire("Registro realizado exitosamente.", "", "success").then(
            (result) => {
              if (result.value) {
                window.location.href = "registro_nota.php";
              }
            }
          );
        } else {
          Swal.fire("Hubo un problema al realizar el registro.", "", "error");
        }
      },
    });
  }
}
```

En este caso defino la variable dataSent, la cual al inicio se declara y asigna con un valor *false*, luego antes de enviar los datos compruebo además de que estos sean validos  que dataSent sea *false* lo cual determina que no sea realizó la petición. En caso de que se cumpla la condición, cambio el valor de *dataSent* a true.

Comment: Deberías decidir que identificador para tus variables usaras, pues veo let y var al mismo tiempo